# where can i find openerp_report_designer plugin?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I found a plugin folder inside base_report_designer but when I added that to apache open office it doesn't show any signs of working. Please can anyone guide me on this I also tried looking at resources or steps mentioned on over various websites but I failed to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Just You can download the `base_report_designer module` from the this link
[Click To Download](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-addons/7.0/view/head:/base_report_designer/plugin/openerp_report_designer.zip)

You should add that module in your OpenERP 7.0 addons directory and install in your system.this module is working fine from my side.

**Reference link for installation Guideline :**

**YouTube :** 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOk6spaWzMg

**Other Web References :** 
http://www.serpentcs.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/OpenERP-Report-Designer.pdf

I hope my answer may helpful for you :)

Comment: Thanks dasadiya, but while enabling the extension i am getting an error

Comment: in the extension manager, the status of the extension is unknown and also   i am getting OpenErp report designer menu in openoffice writer. but I am not able to select any option like Server parameter or so

Comment: Have u checked my reference link ??

Comment: Yes, i did refer it, i am was getting that error on windows OS, but its working fine now but with one error OpenOffice plugin error: The report could not be downloaded, unsupported url

Comment: okey u can download the window related URL for base_report_designer

Comment: yes i am trying to search for that Dasadiya Chaitanya and i am stuck with this issue

Comment: then i switched on to linux based OS and tried with libreoffice, plugin is enabled, but when i click on open a new report, its not showing the popup to select the table or model of my odoo databases

Comment: please can you help me find windows version of plugin ?

Comment: sure I will check if any where I will find any reference link then i will send it to u

Comment: Dasadiya Chaithanya, thanks anyways, odoo instance on my laptop has got crashed, and i am getting ordinal not in range(128) error while re installing it